# Creating df from dict, but renaming the columns not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dictionary

I wish to populate a `Pandas DataFrame` using the values from a dictionary and also change the column names of the `DataFrame` because by default the keys of the `dict` object become the column names. I have the following code snippet :

```
mydict = {'Name':['Anindita'],'Year':[1993]}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict,columns=['a','b'])
print(df)
```

Unfortunately, every time I run this, it creates a blank DataFrame, and the value inside my dictionary object isn't restored. I googled a lot and also came up with a solution like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(mydict.items()),columns=['a','b'])
print(df)             #first creating a list of tuples from the items of the dictionary and then using from_records method to accomplish the same
```

However, I have an instinct that this conversion from `dict` to `list` object isn't necessary and it could have been done with the `dict` object only.

All other ways to do it have failed.

I even thoroughly checked the Pandas `DataFrame` using constructor documentation but couldn't map my problem with what was written.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Please note, I don't wish to only create `DataFrame` from the `dict` object, I have to change the column names of the `DataFrame` as well.
```

Comment: Why not ```df = pd.DataFrame(data=mydict)```?

Comment: But I need to change the column names of the `DataFrame` as well, by default it takes the keys of `mydict` as the column names.

Answer (score 2):

You are closed. Use `index` instead of `columns` then transpose your dataframe:

```
mydict = {'Name': ['Anindita', 'Marcel'], 'Year': [1993, 1970]}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict.values(), index=['a', 'b']).T
print(df)

# Output
          0     1
a  Anindita  1993
b    Marcel  1970
```

If you pass a list of list the orientation of the dataframe is `index` so rename your `index` instead of `columns` then transpose.

Step by step:

```
>>> mydict.values()
dict_values([['Anindita', 'Marcel'], [1993, 1970]])

>>> pd.DataFrame(mydict.values())
          0       1
0  Anindita  Marcel
1      1993    1970

>>> pd.DataFrame(mydict.values(), index=['a', 'b'])
          0       1
a  Anindita  Marcel
b      1993    1970

>>> pd.DataFrame(mydict.values(), index=['a', 'b']).T
          a     b
0  Anindita  1993
1    Marcel  1970
```

If you want to change the orientation, use `zip`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*mydict.values()), columns=['a', 'b'])
print(df)

# Output
          a     b
0  Anindita  1993
1    Marcel  1970
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. However, can you tell me how this works? Why are you taking mydict.values? And why is this not destroying the key-value pairs of the original dictionary?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: Yes I saw it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

After passing in the dictionary, you can rename the columns by passing in another dictionary with the key-value pairs formatted in the following manner, **Original Name : New Name**.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=mydict).rename(columns={"Name":'a',"Year":'b'})
```

**Output:**

```
          a     b
0  Anindita  1993
```

Let me know if this is what you were intending to happen.

**Edit:**
If you wanted to achieve the same thing using a numpy array it is possible like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Anindita', 1993]]), columns =['a','b'])
print(df)
```

The difference is the numpy array doesn't have column names specified, so whatever process is creating the DataFrame in pandas understands to put the array data into columns based on their positions.

From the comments, it is now clear to me that column selection occurs when the data contains column labels (i.e. in a dictionary), which is what leads to the empty rows, rather than any overwriting. When there are no column labels in the data, the provided column labels are taken as the labels for the data.

Comment: As already said, I need to change the column names of the `DataFrame` as well, by default it takes the keys of `mydict` as the column names.

Comment: @QUEEN Let me know if this new output is closer to what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, it is. But I wonder why was it printing an empty `DataFrame` with my code? Was it actually creating a different `dict` object inside when I change the column names so that it couldn't map the original dictionary with the new one?

Comment: @QUEEN So I think the issue is that when you passed in the dictionary, it already has column names vs. if you had passed in something like a numpy array. I think what happens in the case is that the DataFrame is created with the dictionary, and then it overwrites everything with the new column names since you passed in a list ['a','b']. Because there is no data associated with these new names, the rows are blank.

Comment: So by overwrite you mean it searches for `columns 'a' and 'b'` inside the dictionary now for which there are no data in the `dict` object and hence it returns null rows?

Comment: Thank you so much. Also one thing, what would have been the difference if it would have been a `Numpy array`?

Comment: @QUEEN So I am not exactly sure of the internals of how DataFrame creates the object from the argument, but I am thinking if you pass in a list with different names it's interpreted as "Create a new DataFrame with these columns" at a later step. I will include an edit with the numpy array right now.

Comment: yes I think it's actually not overwriting the columns, it just cannot find columns wiht the names `'a','b'` or which it returns null rows. This is because to further test the code, I wrote `df = pd.DataFrame(mydict,columns=['a','Year'])` and it printed the following : `a  Year
0  NaN  1993`. i.e. i now can map the 'Year' column and hence prints its value but cannot find a column with name 'a' so says NaN.

Comment: This explanation of the `columns` behavior is not correct. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html): "If data contains column labels, [`columns`] will perform column selection instead."

Comment: Oh ok, then I misunderstood it. It does not overwrite. You're right in your initial statement.

Comment: @Richard K Yu, yes, thanks for the edit though :)